# A frog hops and lands exactly 1 meter away at a time..

Tags: arithmetic

I am stuck with the following problem:

> A frog hops and lands exactly 1 meter away at a time . What is the least number of hops required to reach a point 10 cm away ?

The options are:

> 1.$\,\,1$
>
> 2.$\,\,2$
>
> 3.$\,\,3$
>
> 4.It can't travel such a distance.

The answer is given to be 2. But I have no clue how to tackle it. Can someone explain. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: HINT: think about a triangle with sides 1m, 1m, 10cm :)

Comment: Well, nobody said the frog has to jump in one dimension (only left/right)

Comment: The question was taken from a competitive exam papers and it carries only 2 marks.

Comment: I just understood, oh, we are on a plane, it's not that you have two directions to hop! So then you can just create a triangle with sides $1,1,0.1$ and hop along. This is a tricky question

Comment: @learner: You get my hint?

Comment: CSIR-UGC NET 2016 June question!

Comment: yeah..Got your hint @freak_warrior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is $2$. This is straightforward, as pointed out in the comment. Since a triangle can be constructed with sides $1m, 1m, $ and $10 cm$; therefore first the frog, say from point A jumps to point B $1m$ apart. Then, the frog jumps to anither point C $1m$ apart but just $10cm $ away from point A thus total displacement being $10 cm$.

Comment: thanks a lot.It makes sense. Got your point.